# Как получить список поддиректорий в директории

Tags: python, файловая-система

Как мне пребрать названия папок в какой либо директории и запихнуть их в переменную через цикл for?

Comment: os.listdir, os.walk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте `os.walk()`.

[Здесь описан ответ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/973473/) на ваш вопрос:

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 2):

Возможно применить модуль [pathlib](https://python-scripts.com/pathlib):

```
from pathlib import Path

my_path = Path(r"c:\Windows\system32\Tasks")
for child in my_path.iterdir():
    if child.is_dir():
        print(child)
```

Вывод:

> ```
> c:\Windows\system32\Tasks\Apple
> c:\Windows\system32\Tasks\Microsoft
> c:\Windows\system32\Tasks\NCH Software
> c:\Windows\system32\Tasks\WPD
> ```